# Rhino Mocks Func asserting Test

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, tdd, rhino-mocks

I need to test that a particular Func is called in Method List ex:

```
public class ProductController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly Func<IProductRepository> prodRepo;
        public ProductController(Func<IProductRepository> _prodRepo)
       {
            prodRepo = _prodRepo;
       } 
        public ActionResult List(string applicationID)
        {
            var products = prodRepo().GetForApp(applicationID).ToList();
            return PartialView("_List",products);
        }
}
```

in this case i need to verify that **prodRepo().GetForApp(applicationID)** whase called.

Comment: Why pass in a Func<IProductRepository> instead of the IProductRepository itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to verify that the Func is called? Or do you need to verify that the ProductController retrieves the products correctly?

If it's the latter, just set up a mock of the IProductRepository to return some products, pass it in via a lambda, and assert that the products you get are the right ones. Generally, if something is providing information (the "arrange" phase in act / arrange / assert, or the "given" in given / when / then) then you want a [*stub* rather than a mock](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+-+Stubs.ashx).

The only time you really need to use a mock and verify that something has been called is when the class under test is delegating a responsibility - for instance, saving a product in the repository.

Also, please check out [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)... it's a bit easier to set up stubs in Moq IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to write your test in *Arrange-Act-Assert* style. You could read more at [Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/blog/3318/rhino-mocks-arrange-act-assert-syntax)

### Arrange phase

First define `MockRepository` and expectations:

```
var mockRepository = new MockRepository();

var repository = mockRepository.StrictMock<IProductRepository>();

using(mockRepository.Record())
{
    repository.Expect(x => x.GetForApp(Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return(new string[0]).Repeat.Once();
}

      var productController = new ProductController((Func<IProductRepository>)(() => repository));
```

### Act phase

Perform action:

```
productController.List("testApplicationID");
```

### Assert phase

Verify results:

```
repository.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

### Missing interface `IProductRepository`

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetForApp(string applicationID);
}
```